# Error message: Installing OpenDaylight "java_home"

Tags: ubuntu, sdn, opendaylight, java-home

I need to install OpenDaylight controller, I've followed the steps, but I got this error message

```
dalal@dalal:~$ sudo ./distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium/bin/karaf
karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
./distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium/bin/karaf: 242: [: Illegal number: 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UnsyncloadClass; support was removed in 11.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/endorsed:/home/dalal/distribution-karaf-0.4.0-Beryllium/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

[image: showing image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Beryllium doesn’t support running on Java 11. Your options are:

- provide a Java 8 runtime, which will work with Beryllium;
- upgrade to Sodium or later, which will work with Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two things going on here.  One looks like it's fatal, but might not be, and the other is definitely fatal.

The first thing you should do at the same shell prompt is run "java -version".  I believe that will likely give you an error of some kind, instead of printing the version of Java you have installed and in your PATH.  If this fails, then you have to properly install Java.

I believe that the message about JAVA_HOME not being set is a red herring.  If I remember correctly, Karaf incorrectly complains about this.  I believe it will work perfectly fine if Java is properly installed and in your PATH.